# Laravel 4 contact form using mail class, error undefined $data from view containing email message

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use Laravel's Mail class for the first time and am having some difficulties. When attempting to submit the contact form to the mail class, I get an undefined variable error.

**Controller**

```
public function store()
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\Contact;

    if($validation->passes()) {

       $fromEmail = Input::get('email');
       $fromName = Input::get('name');
       $subject = "Email from user at website.com";
       $data = Input::get('message');

       $toEmail = 'test@dummyemail.com';
       $toName = 'Mitch Glenn';

       Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){

           $message->to($toEmail, $toName);

           $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

           $message->subject($subject);
       });

    return Redirect::to('/')
        ->with('message', 'Your message was successfully sent!');
    }

    return Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation->errors);
}
```

**View emails.contact**

```
<html>
   <body>
       Message: {{ $data->message }}
   </body>
</html>
```

I am confused why the `$data` variable isn't being passed to the view. I am getting this error: `Undefined variable: data` Thanks for any help or insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change following line

```
$data = Input::get('message');
```

to this

```
$data = [ 'msg' => Input::get('message') ];
```

In your `View` you can use

```
Message: {{ $msg }}
```

**Update:** Don't use `message` as the variable name when passing `data` to the `View`.

Comment: Yes I had used `message` and then changed it to `msg`, now it works - hence why I deleted my comment! Thanks again Sheikh Heera!

Comment: You are welcome and really glad to be with you again -)